# "disapproving" tag in the Cambridge Dictionary

Tags: terminology

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disapproving)

> disapproving: showing that you feel something or someone is bad or wrong

I understand the meaning of it though I don’t understand [the tag in the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jargon).

[image]

Does that mean the word "jargon" is disapproving for some cases? Is "disapproving" a grammar term in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means when we call something "jargon" we usually mean that we disapprove of it.

For example,

> I called tech support, but all they did was spout jargon at me and never fixed the problem.

It means that the tech support person used a lot of fancy words, but never accomplished anything.